With React Native Skia, how can I apply an inner shadow to a Box/Rect with a transparent fill?
I'm trying to render an inner Shadow inside a Rect, where the Rect has a color with 0'ed alpha channel (e.g. opacity: 0 or color: #ffffff00 or color: 'transparent'). Below is the code:
<Canvas style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <Group>
    <Rect
      x={0}
      y={0}
      width={screenWidth}
      height={screenHeight}
      color="transparent"
    />
    <Shadow inner dx={12} dy={12} blur={30} color="red" />
    <Shadow inner dx={-12} dy={-12} blur={30} color="blue" />
  </Group>
</Canvas>

This renders an empty canvas. I can get the Shadows to render correctly if I give the Rect an opaque color, but I'd like the Rect to be transparent.
I've also futzed around with layer and clip but to no avail. Could someone please point me in the right direction?
